# Android JSON Parser "User cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, android, json

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public List readJsonStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
try {
    return readMessagesArray(reader);
} finally {
    reader.close();
}
}
public List readMessagesArray(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {

List messages = new ArrayList();

reader.beginArray();
while (reader.hasNext()) {
    messages.add(readMessage(reader));
}
reader.endArray();
return messages;
}

public Message readMessage(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {

long id = -1;
String text = null;
User user = null;
List geo = null;

reader.beginObject();
while (reader.hasNext()) {
    String name = reader.nextName();
if(name.equals("id")) {
id = reader.nextLong();
} else if (name.equals("text")) {
  text = reader.nextString();
} else if (name.equals("geo") && reader.peek() != JsonToken.NULL) {
  geo = readDoublesArray(reader);
} else if (name.equals("user")) {
  user = readUser(reader);
} else {
  reader.skipValue();
}
}
reader.endObject();
return new Message(id, text, user, geo);
}
public List readDoublesArray(JsonReader reader)throws IOException {
    List doubles = new ArrayList();

    reader.beginArray();
    return doubles;
}
public User readUser(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    String username = null;
    int followersCount = -1;

    reader.beginObject();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
    String name = reader.nextName();
    if(name.equals("name")) {
        username = reader.nextString();
    } else if (name.equals("followers_count")) {
        followersCount = reader.nextInt();
    } else {
        reader.skipValue();
    }
    }
    reader.endObject();
    return new User(username, followersCount);
     }}
```

I'm using the exact example from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html. However, there is a problem with "User cannot be resolved to a type".

Comment: Do you actually have a User class and is it imported?

Comment: Hi, no I don't. I followed exactly the example and faced this problem.

Answer (score 0):

'User' class in the given example is just to show how it may work. You may substitute it with something like this:

```
public class User{
  String name;
  int followers_count;

  public User(String name, int followers_count){
   this.name=name;
   this.followers_count=followers_count;
  }

}
```